# Fill SKShapeNode the texture

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I do not speak English, I will be brief, sorry.

I have `SKShapeNode`, size 100x10000, how do I fill it the texture?

I used this method: https://gist.github.com/man1/413642637ebd0b00fe2b

It is not suitable due to the fact that he spends a lot of RAM and does not create 100x10000 size of the texture.

I used `SKScopNode` for that would cut texture on a path `SKShapeNode`, and it was that necessary, but only for `iOS10`... `iOS9` can not use SKShapeNode as a mask.

Cut `SKShapeNode` into smaller pieces, in my case, it is inconvenient and not practical. Are there any other ways to fill `SKShapeNode` the texture?

**UPD:** I forgot to clarify. `SKShapeNode` uneven. Just copy/paste the texture is not suitable.

[image]

Comment: This might help u https://xcodenoobies.blogspot.my/2015/08/skspritekit-how-to-fill-skscene.html

Comment: I'm not sure what  you're trying to do, but this sounds like a candidate for https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sktilemapnode

Comment: @Confused  Thanks, but unfortunately `SKTileMapNode` only for iOS 10.0+

Comment: @GeneCode Sorry, I update post: copy/paste the texture is not suitable.

Comment: Sorry, @xXxxX (great user name, btw) I missed the bit about iOS 9. I live on the wild side (betas) all the time.

Comment: Is there any chance you can use Core Animation instead of SpriteKit to render these shapes?

Comment: @Confused Shape have physical properties.. perhaps may be overlay on over of the texture desired form?

Answer (score 1):

This way is not efficient. I am guessing you want to make a platform for your game level right? Your sprite of 100x10000 pix will take a lot of memory and not good for your game design. What you should do is divide the platform into small pieces (with same width as your screen) and load it as your character moves forward. And when the platform is out of the screen, remove it from scene (thereby saving memory), and load another one at the front.

[image]

Read this article to learn about this:https://digitalleaves.com/blog/2013/12/parallax-scrolling-in-spritekit-made-easy/

Comment: Good job! I couldn't deduce what he needed this massive thing for, so couldn't quite grok what to do about breaking it apart into smaller bits. I think you've nailed it. And great blog post!